# share AC_DEFINE trough AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS in autoconf

Tags: c, autotools, autoconf

I have two progrects using autoconf. Project A uses project B through  AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS()

project A configure.ac:

```
AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS([projectb])
```

project B configure.ac:

```
AC_DEFINE([NEWDEFINE])
```

I would like to export the NEWDEFINE from project B to project A.

a.c:

```c
#ifndef NEWDEFINE
#error NEWDEFINE not defined
#endif
```

```shell
$ autoreconf
$ ./configure
$ make
a.c:2:2: error: #error PTHREAD not defined
    2 | #error NEWDEFINE not defined
      |  ^~~~~
```

I want to view the NEWDEFINE in a.c of project A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to export the NEWDEFINE from project B to project A.

`AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS` is for configuring a bundled standalone project.  The configuration of such a project is its own.  If you're looking for an *external* macro of such a project, as built, then you will find it in one of the project's public headers, which the project A sources that need it should `#include`.  Possibly a generated header.

If the macro you want is not accessible that way then to a first approximation, it is not available at all.  That is, project A's build should not be made dependent on internal build details of project B or any other separate project.  Alternatives include:

- Do without.
- Use your knowledge of project B's configuration script and the options it will be called with to predict the definition it will produce.
- Hack your copy of project B to expose the definition to you in an existing or new public header, or, better, to allow project A to *control* what the definition will be.
- If project B uses `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS`, so that the macro definition will be written in a `config.h` for that project (which is an *internal* header), then get it from there in any of a number of ways.  The absolute worst of those would be to `#include` project B's `config.h` directly into your regular sources -- do not do this.
- If you really need internal build configuration of project B inside project A, then perhaps that's a sign that they shouldn't really be separate projects.  You could merge them together under control of a single configuration script, which would of course have all the relevant information.

Any way around, you cannot get data generated by project B's `configure` into project A's `configure` when the former is run by the latter under control of `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS`. The structure and timing do not work for that.